# Links are only working on mobile but not desktop

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, modernizr

The links to my sites are only working on mobile but when I visite it via desktop none of the links work; the url changes but it doesn't actually go to the link unless I click into the address bar and press enter.

I am not getting any errors in the console and when I ran aXe to analyze the site everything came back good.

```
<nav class="cb-navbar">
<div class="cb-container">
  <div class="cb-navbar-inner">
    <div class="cb-navbar-left">
      <a href="index.html" class="cb-navbar-back">
        <i class="cb-icon -long-arrow-left"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="index.html" class="cb-navbar-logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="cb-navbar-right">
      <div class="cb-navbar-nav">
        <a href="/services/index.html" id="navbar-services" class="cb-navbar-nav-item">
                <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-icon">
                    <i class="cb-icon -cog"></i>
                </span>
          <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-text">Services</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/projects/index.html" id="navbar-projects" class="cb-navbar-nav-item">
                <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-icon">
                    <i class="cb-icon -bars"></i>
                </span>
          <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-text">Projects</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/contacts/index.html" onclick="yaCounter.reachGoal('contacts')" id="navbar-contacts" class="cb-navbar-nav-item">
                <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-icon">
                    <i class="cb-icon -contacts"></i>
                </span>
          <span class="cb-navbar-nav-item-text">Contacts</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using `href` and `onclick` on same element, this might be creating an issue. Add code of `yaCounter.reachGoal` method

Comment: which version of bootstrap are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 3.3.7. 

@AkanshGulati are you saying I should be using that on all of the links?

Comment: The website is instastatus.live

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the whole file? From what you posted, I copied into a running application and replaced the navbar, and the links both worked mobile and on desktop.

You are however missing a closing  tag, not sure if you have yours closed that may be causing the issue.

Comment: This is not an answer, should be a comment